# Any Cloud Print API For ANDROID

Tags: android, java, google-cloud-print

Does anyone know if there is a Cloud print API for Android? .To develop our own Cloud print Apk for Android device. 
Any tutorial or Sample code for this will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

There is an Google Cloud Print API available which I wrote a while back:
http://cloudx.fun2code.de/en/api.html

JavaDoc and examples are also available.

For a more detailed example have a look at the blog entry:
http://fun2code-blog.blogspot.de/2011/10/setting-up-cloud-print-printer-using.html

Hope that helps...

Comment: Links appear to be broken.

Answer (score 1):

Check this for Google Cloud Print integration with Android.

https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/android

Answer (score 0):

Printing is not yet supported on Android. You have to use a 3rd party solution for that!!

You can  add printing functionality to your Android application by integrating with Google [Cloud Print](https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/android)

Comment: But Various Cloud Print apk available on Google Store what method they used to print the document

Comment: I tried integrating that but after listing printer registered with that account api got crashed .. Any Help

Answer (score 0):

You can use iPrint sdk but it is paid for per user basis.

Link : http://www.iprintsdk.com/

Comment: I dont want to use any 3rd Party any Open Source Suggestion  ? ?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what you'd be printing so...

For normal printers and letter-sized documents, you should use Google Cloud Print as recommended previously. Google Cloud Print is the best and simplest solution out there for these printers.

Other alternatives are writing your own printer driver which is probably not even worth attempting because of how complex it is to implement perfect support or sending your print jobs through a 3rd party printing app that's already been made which probably will not provide the level of customization you want to provide.

For receipt printers, Star Micronics offers a well documented Android SDK package with lots of print samples here: http://www.starmicronics.com/support/SDKDocumentation.aspx

A printing API is included to handle status, open/close port, and basic communication. The SDK includes a sample app with a bunch of samples you can try out to get your receipt looking exactly how you want.

Comment: I would be printing Office Document and PDF file

Comment: Check these links out: https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/devguide ~ and ~ Python samples: https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/pythonCode

Comment: But i have to develop it for Android

Comment: To my knowledge, that Python sample is the most complete one available at this time. It's the wrong language, but at least it's a great reference. I would reach out to a printer company and see if they have an API and a sample they can give you as a developer.

Comment: @LtH the starmicronics is only for its own printers right? Do you know if there's anything which is more generic?

Comment: Check this for Android integration https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/android