# Calling google cloud print to print a local file from an android app

Tags: java, android, printing, google-cloud-print

I have a text file and I want to print it with google print. Does anyone has any idea how to do that?

Comment: what have you tried so far? reading the introduction provided by google? http://www.google.com/cloudprint/learn/ - or do you want to do it programmatically?

Comment: with java programmatically. I will add a tag.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203924/any-cloud-print-api-for-android or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468266/using-the-google-cloud-print-api-with-android or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725122/how-to-print-android-activity-display-using-cloud-print then